# Random 128bit peppers when encrypting passwords

Tags: php, security, hash

I am developing a new web application using PHP 7.2 and I am considering the following approach to maximise security for passwords. Here is what I am planning to do:

1. A PHP file contains an array with 100 constant tokens that are 128 bits in length (randomly generated in the beginning)
2. When a user registers

   1. Pseudo-randomly pick a pepper from the array (`array_rand()`) and store the index in the SQL database
   2. Encrypt the password string using `hash_hmac("sha256", $password, $pepper);` (where `$pepper` is a random 128 bit alphanumeric token from the pre-defined list)
   3. Hash the password using Argon2i (argon2id not available for my server)
3. When the user logs in

   1. To check the password, fetch the pepper, encrypt the password again and match it: `password_verify(hash_hmac("sha256", $_POST["password"], $pepper), $row["password"])`

Do you think that this approach of using peppers effectively improves security? Could there be any potential flaws and exploits, specifically with PHP?

I saw on several forums that others recommend using a system-specific constant (e.g. something that's unique for hardware + software configuration of the server), use a single pepper only, etc. My point in implementing this is that if an attacker successfully obtains the users DB with an SQL Injection (for example), they would probably still not have access to my `peppers.php` code. I think that using a single pepper can easily be brute-forced. What I like about my idea is that I can always scale this algorithm on multiple servers or increase the pre-defined peppers freely.

Comment: While I don't see an immediate flaw in this, it doesn't really add anything more than a standard pepper and it just adds unnecessary complexity.

Comment: @Narf My concern is that if I use one pepper only, a skilful attacker could potentially crack it through brute-force

Comment: Your concern is unfounded. In fact, this isn't even a pepper ... A pepper is supposed to be stored only in the code, as its entire purpose is to mitigate a possible database breach; storing it in the database makes it just a second salt, which is useless.

Comment: @Narf The pepper is not stored on the DB, its array index is (0-99). This index can't be used by the attacker unless they have the complete set of peppers.

Comment: Ok, sure, it's a pepper then ... Still doesn't need to be an array of possible values and all that logic. You're trying to invent a solution to a problem that doesn't exist. I guess it's fine, just don't see the point in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more about IT security or cryptography, but let's assume that mentioning PHP is enough to perform a small protocol analysis on StackOverflow.

The idea of a salt is that it is unique. That way rainbow tables cannot be constructed and identical passwords cannot be distinguished. A salt is commonly stored with the password hash and should be considered public.

The idea of a pepper is that it remains secret, so that the password hash cannot be created by an attacker that doesn't have access to it. That means that it is impossible for an attacker to guess the password.

Now you've defined a scheme where no salt seems to be used and the pepper is *somewhat* unique. That's not much good when it isn't; creating 100 rainbow tables seems expensive but feasible, for instance. Furthermore, you will have to store multiple peppers / secrets, rather than just one.

Creating random salts and peppers (both 128 bits) is more secure than your scheme. The HMAC is not needed: you can specify a key for Argon2i. If you cannot, concatenate the salt and pepper and use those as salt (or take the hash over the concatenation and use that, if the salt parameter is limited).

Comment: From what I've seen on some forums, people tend to use 1 pepper for everything, so it's the same for every password, this makes me think that once that one pepper is cracked, the attacker _has access_ to all passwords. What I am trying to do is use more peppers by randomly selecting one for each user from 100 available. This means that cracking one pepper would potentially reveal 1% of the passwords only. This method allows me to add more peppers infinitely as more accounts are registered, as I simply have to append them to a PHP array.

Comment: Yeah, OK, but if the access to the keys doesn't differ, then the same attacks will apply to all keys instead of one. It's better to protect one key really well than 100 haphazardly.

Comment: Um, 2 clarifications ... 1st on a part of the answer - one doesn't need to think about a salt, because PHP's `password_hash()` will create one automatically and rainbow tables aren't applicable. 2nd on @williamd5's comment - the pepper being leaked doesn't automatically mean all passwords are revealed, Argon2i is strong enough to guarantee that passwords are fine with or without a pepper; however, pepper will to some extent protect the easiest passwords from being cracked with a dictionary attack.

Comment: Ah, yes, alright, if the salt is automatically generated then sure. I do however take issue with "Argon2i is strong enough to guarantee that passwords are fine with or without a pepper;". That's simply not true, many passwords do simply not contain enough entropy, and using a salt & work factor will only require a constant factor more work. No password hash can claim that kind of security. It's a mitigation strategy; if you use "HelloWorld" (or worse) as password then a DB with salt & password hash will leak it if the attacker just tries all common passwords.

Comment: Naturally, password strength is another concern. I meant that as a way to emphasize that a leaked pepper doesn't equal cracking an entire database of passwords, which is what OP said in his first comment.

Comment: Oh, yeah, that is correct, if you leak the pepper the security will be identical to the password hash without the pepper. It won't be zero for sure, all's not lost :)

Comment: @Narf definitely it doesn't leak the entire database, but having cracked one pepper allows you to proceed cracking all passwords using a dictionary attack, brute-force, or whatever. In the algorithm that I suggested there are 100 different peppers (more can be added dynamically at any time), so you have to crack each of them as well. Having cracked 1 pepper, limits your leak to a maximum of 1% (since only 1% of users will be using that pepper and not 100%), shall you manage to crack all hashes having that pepper.

Comment: I get your point @williamd5, but you make it sound like that's child's play and it simply isn't. For one, an attacker wouldn't know that a pepper is being used without knowing your code, or the way it is applied (prefix, suffix, hmac key like you thought of, etc.); then even with that aside, a pepper cannot be "cracked" on its own - it would have to be brute-forced together with the password ... If it ever gets out, it's going to be by leaked code, not cracking hashes. Using a single strong pepper is more than enough.